Error When install python3-dev or python3.12-dev
i have a error when install python3-dev or python3.12-dev.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.12-venv : Depends: python3.12 (= 3.12.3-1) but 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I install this package in this below :
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

How to resolve this problem?

The package in the message is correct (python3.12 | 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1 | noble-security | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x) so I'd likely check python3.12-venv to ensure you haven't put a hold or something is wrong there..  that should be python3.12-venv | 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.1 | noble-security/universe  (ie. using apt policy etc)

@guiverc Same problem here. The answer that is linked didn't help.

I did:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-dev



I've tried this, but i get same error
